# Has an NFL team ever beat two divisional opponents in the playoffs?

Tags: nfl, postseason

Has an NFL team ever beat two teams from its own division in the NFL playoffs?

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2023, this happened most recently in the [2021 playoffs](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/#all_playoff_results).

The Los Angeles Rams defeated the Arizona Cardinals in the Wild Card round, then after defeating Tampa Bay, defeated the San Francisco 49ers in the NFC Championship prior to winning the Super Bowl over the Bengals.

Prior to that, in [1985 (1986 Super Bowl)](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1985/#all_playoff_results), the New England Patriots defeated the New York Jets in the Wild Card round, then after defeating the Raiders in the Divisional round, defeated the Miami Dolphins in the AFC Championships, prior to losing the Super Bowl to the Bears.

Comment: Interestingly, the easiest time for this to happen outside of 2021->present (the 7 team playoffs) was the period with 3 divisions and 3 wildcards in the 1990s, which failed to return a case of this happening even when having *all three* wildcards in the same division twice (the NFC Central, both times!)

Comment: Also, the Dolphins beat both the Jets and the Patriots in the 1982-3 playoffs, but that's definitely a special case.